# Red5 upload/record: M4A, not FLV

Tags: flash, streaming, flv, red5, m4a

I am streaming audio web to a RED5 server, and currently the file seems to be stored in FLV format. I want to store it in a different format, say M4A.

Is that possible at all? I am not too hung up on M4A, and open to different formats, but something other than FLV. If it is possible, what configuration files do I need to change for that?

Thanks.

EDIT: As background information, I want the uploaded file to be playable on iOS devices. iPhone doesn't support flv format. So any format that iOS supports is good with me. I just fear that Red5 only records in FLV, is that the case?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't configure red5 to store the file in a different format. But you can install FFMPEG and add a Job/Code a converter that converts all your FLVs in mp4, mp3 or whatever you want it.